# Is there anything stopping the crownholder taking the King card every turn?

Tags: citadels

My understanding is that the special rules regarding the King are:

- If the King is turned face up at the pre-distribution phase, it goes back into the deck.
- If the King is targeted by the Assassin, the crown still changes player.

The question I have is - if the current crown-holder always chooses the King as their card, then the crown will never change hands.

Is this a correct understanding of the rules?

Comment: I did not know the king had to be shuffled back in if drawn face up.   Ive mostly played this game with 6/7 players and not had a face up card.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Your second point seems incorrect, if the king is assassinated the crown does not change player but stays with the current king.

Comment: @Bazzz No it doesn't. The rules specifically make this point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting the crown is usually a small reward in comparison to, say, the architect or the thief abilities. The only way this can be a good strategy is focusing on golden districts. At that point, is it easy to target the king with either the thief or the assasin and break the advantage of having the crown AND a useful ability.

In short, there is no way of stopping some player keeping the king forever, but there is also not a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If the king holder always takes the king then they will become an easy target for other players when they take the assassin or the thief. If they only pick the king then they will end up hurting themselves as there is no real benefit to always being the crown holder that would make up for losing the other abilities.